# Nginx and Magento 1.13 running URL migration script

Tags: upgrade, url-rewrite, ee-1.13, nginx

I have to upgrade to 1.14 from 1.11 and have to go through 1.13, and the long `url_migration_to_1_13.php` script.

The website is running on NGinx, and I know the script can run on multiple thread with the command `php -f shell/url_migration_to_1_13.php 7`

Do I need to set up thread pooling and such on Nginx? Is there anyway to make the script go faster?

Answer (score -1):

no nginx involved, this is just a php=>mysql operation, so make sure you have enough CPU and obviously SSD storage will help a lot.